# How to get MIME Type of a file to be downloaded?

Tags: php, download, mime-types

I Have to download the listed file on click of the link, for whic I have used the below scripot, but I when the file gets dowloaded, it cannot idenetify the extension of downloaded file. So, How to get MIME Type of a file to be downloaded? _Please Help...

```
$filename = $_GET['val'];
         // Fetch the file info.
    $filePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "dfms/images/uploads/".$filename;


    if(file_exists($filePath)) {
        echo $fileName = basename($filePath);
        $fileSize = filesize($filePath);

        // Output headers.
        header("Cache-Control: private");
        header("Content-Type: application/octet");
        header("Content-Length: ".$fileSize);
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName);

        // Output file.
        readfile ($filePath);                   
        exit();
    }
    else {
        die('The provided file path is not valid.');
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the finfo_file function from the FileInfo extension (enabled by default in PHP 5.3).
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

From the example in the documentation

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
finfo_close($finfo);
```

In PHP versions prior to 5.3 the pecl extension can be installed http://pecl.php.net/package/Fileinfo

However in this case it requires the magic_open (libmagic) library http://sourceforge.net/projects/libmagic

The alternative is to use the deprecated function `mime_content_type($filename)` http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Which relies on the mime.magic file

Comment: Its not working!!!it give me...
Warning: finfo_open() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given in C:\wamp\www\dfms\support-scripts\download.php on line 24

Warning: finfo_file(): supplied argument is not a valid file_info resource in C:\wamp\www\dfms\support-scripts\download.php on line 25

Comment: I think Jacob may have mistyped his example. The first line should read `$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);` that's just reading the documentation over at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php

Comment: FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE has been available since 5.3, FILEINFO_MIME is as defined by RFC 2045 so the former should be used if available.

Comment: OM The Eternity may not be running PHP 5.3 in that case :p

Comment: mime_content_type() is not deprecated function.