# request and read any file type with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, get

so this is what I'm trying to do:
I'm trying to be able to get CSS, JS, and HTML files from a  php file I want to Echo them in the php file, and set the type in the file to the needed type ex: if it is a js file set the type to `text/javascript` if it's css set the type to `text/css` im saying the *doc type btw* the page type, the header type. I don't know what it's called but I want the browser to interpret it as the file type even though it would be technically html.
I have some code typed up..

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['type'])) {
        if ($_GET['type'] === 'javascript') {
            header('Content-type: text/javascript; charset: UTF-8');
            $file = $_GET['name'].'.js';
            $execjs = file_get_contents($file);
        }
    } elseif ($_GET['type'] === 'css') {
        header('Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8');
        $file = $_GET['name'].'.css';
        $execcss = file_get_contents($file);
    }
} if ($execjs === 'false') {
    echo 'js 404';
} elseif ($execcss === 'false') {
    echo 'css404';
}
?>
```

but this does not work for the 2 file type I have chosen, it uses `$_GET['name'] (Name in the query string)` and `$_GET['type'] (type in the query string)` to get the file name and file type, I also want to make it universal so it can read almost any file type, ex 
`js, css, php, html, xml, png, ico, jpg`
I understand that this may be hard to do, I just need some starter code to get me going on building the file

Comment: You should use finfo_file as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966045/how-to-get-mime-type-of-a-file-to-be-downloaded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like:

```
<?php

$name = $_GET['name'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
if (!isset($name)) {
    die();
}
if (!isset($type)) {
    die();
}
switch ($type) {
    case "javascript":
    $header = 'Content-type: text/javascript; charset: UTF-8';
    $file = $name.'.js';
    break;
    case "css":
    $header = 'Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8';
    $file = $name.'.css';
    break;
    case "php":
    $header = 'Content-type: text/html; charset: UTF-8';
    $file = $name.'.html';
    break;
}
$execfile = file_get_contents($file);
if ($execfile === false) {
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset: UTF-8');
    echo $type.' 404';
} else {
    header($header);
    echo $execfile;
}
?>
```

Comment: this works for the most part, a few syntax errors after the declaration of a variable<br>`$name = $_GET['name']`<br>there must be a semicolon (;) at the end of this string otherwise it will trigger an error.<br>and, with the `if (!isset($name) {` you must close as many brackets as you open so.. `if (!isset($name**)**) {`<br>also I assume the server finds the file as otherwise it returns a 404 as specified but it will not list the contents of the file, and I was wondering can the header type be set back to `text/html` when there is a 404?

Comment: mostly worked once agian, after a few tweaks. in the `header('Content-type: text/html; charset: UTF-8')` after `if ($execfile === false) {` there needs to be a semi- colin at the end of this and in the css header it says `text/javascript` this needs to be `text/css` (sorry just recommending fixes to make it work) it will read all of the code to the file now.

Comment: this works 100%! I was just wondering if there's a way to make it where there is a &dir=<directory> so I can get files in different directories without the hap-hazard use in the name, also if you do this please edit off of [this](https://pastebin.com/yTFQCJL3) it's my own edit of the main code, makes it actually echo the html brackets and adds htm and html